# php search form

Tags: php, mysql, search

am fiddling around with a search form i've managed to string together which works. In total there is a possibility to input 28 values including checkbox's and selection options. So i have this code repeated 28 times with different variables, is there a shorter way to do this, it looks so nasty in my code which leads me to believe am doing something very wrong. Here is an example of my code:

```
            $search_shop_name = '';

            if(isset($_GET['search_shop_name'])) {
            $search_shop_name = $_GET['search_shop_name']; 
    }               
    else {
        $search_shop_name = '';
    }
```

That is just 1 piece of code for one input, imagine how long and sloppy this code is. Any advice would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`filter_input()`<sup>[docs]</sup>](http://php.net/filter_input). It will shorten your code to a single line:

```
$search_shop_name = filter_input('search_shot_name', INPUT_GET);
```

Or do something like this:

```
// put your default values here
$defaults = array(
    'search_shop_name' => '',
    'other_value' => '',
    ...
);

// merge $_GET in default values
$input = array_merge($defaults, $_GET); // or $_GET + $defaults

// you are done
$search_shop_name = $input['search_shop_name'];
```

Comment: the second answer worked Perfectly, thanks so much. i must read up on this array_merge. Code looks alot tidier now.

Comment: Hi, ive been reading about injection and fiddling with, strip_tags, strip_slashes, mysql_real_escape and htmlspecialchars. But enter a element: <h1>,  the H1 takes effect and breaks the site. Am trying to prevent tags from being inserted into the input box.  I have considered a large number of options for a select menu to ensure the user doesn't type in tags.

Comment: Just use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when you echo a variable. Don't filter input. Escape output. Just do `echo htmlspecialchar($variable)`.

Comment: i've input <h1> to test this and i returns: &lt;h1&gt;

I have read that i MUST escape data users enter. Are there any websites or programmes to show my websites vunerabilities rather than putting it online to get taken apart in no time ?

Comment: That's wrong, you must only escape data you output. Not the input.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using all those conditionals, you could simply do:

```
$search_shop_name = $_GET['search_shop_name'];
```

If the `$_GET` value isn't set, then `$search_shop_name` will be an empty string.

Comment: If it isn't set, it'll emit an E_NOTICE. I find it a good habit to write code that doesn't do that.

Comment: This triggers errors if $_GET['search_shop_name'] is not set. I believe this is what OP tries to avoid by using isset().